# Order of class in n_support_ (sklearn svm)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm

In the [sklearn SVM SVC documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) I was trying to figure out in what order of classes does the n_support_ attribute give the number of Support Vectors. I couldn't find it mentioned anywhere. Please, can somebody tell me how I can find that out?

Example: For binary classification of classes -1,+1

```
In []: print (svm_fit.n_support_)
Out[]: [6388 6383]
```

Now here I am not sure which class does the first value belong to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a slightly modified version of the example provided in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html):

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1]])
y = np.array([-1, -1, 1, 1])
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X, y)
print(f'Number of support vectors in each class: {clf.n_support_}')
print(f'Classes: {clf.classes_}')
```

you can access the classes of the classifier by calling `.classes_`.

The code above prints out:

> Number of support vectors in each class: [2 2]
>
> Classes: [-1  1]

which means 2 belong to the `-1` class, 2 belong to the `1` class.